# Can I use Javabeans with hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, jsp, javabeans

I'm using a **hibernate2** plugin in my web project with jsp. My project also contains a register page.

Can I use **Javabeans** to send information from a html `<form>` using hibernate's class? Without hibernate I created a class with get and set like this:

```
package com.java2s;

public class Lang {
    private String choix;
    private String comm;

    public String getChoix() {
        return choix;
    }

    public void setChoix(String choix) {
        this.choix = choix;
        //System.out.println(choix);
    }

    public String getComm() {
        return comm;
    }

    public void setComm(String comm) {
        this.comm = comm;
        // System.out.println(comm);
    }

}
```

but I know that hibernate generates a get and set class and receives it with:

```
<jsp:useBean id='user' class='com.java2s.Lang'  type='com.java2s.Lang' scope='session' />
<jsp:setProperty name='user' property='*'/>
```

any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i get what i need i call `MyDB.Etudinat` from the pakage genrated by hibernate
on a beans in my jsp page

and i save it like that

```
 <%
if(user.getUserName()!=null){

Session hibernateSession = MyDB.HibernateUtil.currentSession(); 
   Transaction tx = hibernateSession.beginTransaction();
   Etudinat etudiant = new Etudinat(); 
     etudiant.setUserName(user.getUserName());
       etudiant.setPassword(user.getPassword());
       etudiant.setEmail(user.getEmail());
       etudiant.setNom(user.getNom());
       etudiant.setPrenom(user.getPrenom());
     etudiant.setSexe(user.getSexe());
    etudiant.setQuestion(user.getQuestion());
     etudiant.setAnswer(user.getAnswer());
     etudiant.setIDFilliere(Filliere.INFORMATIQUE);
 /* out.print("<Li>"+user.getUserName());
  out.print("<Li>"+user.getPassword());
  out.print("<Li>"+user.getEmail());
  out.print("<Li>"+user.getNom());
  out.print("<Li>"+user.getPrenom());
  out.print("<Li>"+user.getSexe());
  out.print("<Li>"+user.getQuestion());
  out.print("<Li>"+user.getAnswer());

  */
hibernateSession.save(etudiant);
tx.commit();
 HibernateUtil.closeSession();
 }
  %>
```

i wish that will help outhers

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate 2?  The current version is 3.6.5; I'd upgrade.  Your JSP should not have any Hibernate code in it; it should submit the form to a servlet, which will validate and bind the request parameters to objects and then persist using Hibernate.

Comment: and when i want to select from table and print it on a jsp page , how can i do that in the current jsp page ??? could you give me an exemple about send information from register page and save them as a seesion in hibernate with out using request.getParameter() ??

Comment: No examples from me, but I can tell you that I'd break the problem into pieces.  You make it sound like it'll happen in one go, but there are several components: credential objects, a data access interface with Hibernate as its implementation, a servlet/service to bind, validate, and consume the request.  Work on small pieces and knit them together into the complete solution.  Or go write PHP.

Comment: i get what i need you can see that on my next answer , thank you sir for your answer